# Selecting option in parent dropDownList does not send updated value to child dropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two dropDownLists that are being used to populate data in the view model of a partial view. One of the dropDownLists cascades from the other. As I change the selection of the parent, the child datasource doesn't receive the updated value.

This is the partial view (which can be on the page multiple times):

```
@model ViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Parent.Id)
              .Name("Parent_" + Model.Id)
              .OptionLabel("Select parent...")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Id")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetParentOptions", "Controller");
                  });
              })
)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Child.Id)
              .Name("Child_" + Model.Id)
              .OptionLabel("Select child...")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Id")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetChildOptions", "Controller", new { parentId = Model.Parent.Id });
                  })
                      .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("Parent_" + Model.Id)
)
```

And here are the Controller actions:

```
public JsonResult GetParentOptions()
{
    var options = ParentService.GetOptions();

    return Json(options, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetChildOptions(int? parentId)
{
    var options = ChildService.GetOptions(parentId);

    return Json(options, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong `ParentId` to the controller. That `ParentId` is the one coming from the Model, when the page is loaded, and will remain the same. What you need to pass to the controller is the `ParentId` selected by the user from the parent drop-down list. Here's how you do it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Parent.Id)
     .Name("Parent_" + Model.Id)
     .OptionLabel("Select parent...")
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Id")
     .DataSource(source =>
     {
         source.Read(read =>
         {
             read.Action("GetParentOptions", "Controller");
         });
     })
)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Child.Id)
     .Name("Child_" + Model.Id)
     .OptionLabel("Select child...")
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Id")
     .DataSource(source =>
     {
         source.Read(read =>
         {
             read.Action("GetChildOptions", "Controller")
                  .Data("filterParentId");

         })
             .ServerFiltering(true);
     })
     .Enable(false)
     .AutoBind(false)
     .CascadeFrom("Parent_" + Model.Id)
)

<script>
    function filterParentId() {
        return {
            parentId: $("#Parent_@Model.Id").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

By the way, you don't need to override the Name property. When you use `DropDownListFor` the name will be derived from the Propery Name coming from `ModelMetadata`.

**UPDATE:**

I'd recommend giving an `id` to your drop-down lists instead of overwriting the `name` (if you have to). Here's how you do it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Parent.Id)
     .OptionLabel("Select parent...")
     .DataTextField("Text")
     .DataValueField("Id")
     .DataSource(source =>
     {
         source.Read(read =>
         {
             read.Action("GetParentOptions", "Controller");
         });
     })
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Parent_" + Model.Id })        
)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!

I used the Name property because I will be using it for stuff in other javascript code. Is there a different way to do that?

Comment: @Kibner, Kendo already assigned a Name to your drop-down list. Remove the Name property, and look at the source in your browser to see what name is assigned. The Name is the name the property in your Model, but in your case, it's a little bit more complicated, so that's why I'm asking you to check the page source.

However, if you want to assign your own name, for the sake of simplicity, I'd recommend using the id instead of name. check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I'm a bit new to Kendo and still not fully comfortable with MVC, so this advice helps me a lot.